# How can I hide a button using javascript or only css when user clicks outside the div?

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to hide the button when user clicks outside the div, it is working as expected when user clicks inside the document (oustide the div) but lets say user clicks on other open browser tab or window then too the button should hide.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/neerajmasai/pen/zYayqmP)

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const box = document.querySelector('#box');
  if( ! box.contains(event.target) ) {
    document.querySelector('#btn').style.display = 'none';
  }
  else{
    document.querySelector('#btn').style.display = 'initial';
  }
})
```

In the above codepen example, the button hides as expected when clicked outside the div but does not hide when user switches tabs or clicks anywhere else on the screen. It should hide even when the user clicks anywhere outside the div, not only limited to the currently open document.

Comment: Add a `blur` handler for `window`, and make that also hide the element?

Comment: It looks like you want to subscribe to a different event, not only the click. Try this (in addition to the code you have).

`document.addEventListener("visibilitychange",(event)=>{
      document.querySelector('#btn').style.display = 'none';
})`

Comment: For more information, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution to the problem, many thanks.